# No module named _imagingcms on OSX

Tags: python, django, python-imaging-library, importerror

Today i've tried to test a django project on my macbook, but whenever i try to start it, i get the same error: "Error: No module named _imagingcms".

Seems like something is missng from PIL. I've tried to reinstall PIL, but it does not help.

What should i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, installing lcms from macports and reinstalling PIL helped.